# Delete rows from tables with similar name. CASCADE not available

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete

We have a database that is managed by an external system, so we don't have access to create foreign keys for cascade deletes, etc.

The thing is we want to delete rows from tables that have a similar name. For example we can have 3 tables named like this:

```
dbo.[test$Sales Line$1]
dbo.[test$Sales Line$2]
dbo.[test$Sales Line$3]
```

What we do currently is we get the tables with a query like:

```
select t.name as table_name 
from sys.tables t 
where t.name like 'test$Sales Line$%'
```

Then we have to loop through each table, and delete the rows we need.

Wondering if there is a faster solution; something like

```
DELETE FROM dbo.[test$Sales Line$%] 
WHERE DocNo = 'A1001'
```

Comment: Change (fix) the design and have one table, not three, as these tables seem to be the same "thing" with different numbered values? Then you only need one `DELETE` statement. An object's name shouldn't represent data that should be in a column; for the sample you have it seems you should have 1 table called `Sales` with a column called `Line` with values like `1`, `2`, and `3`.

Comment: No, you can't use variables or similar constructs instead of table names.

Comment: @Larnu As I said, we don't have access to modify the table design or create foreign keys. I wish we had this option, but unfortunately we don´t. The reason for having multiple tables, is because the host system has an extension functionality, so they have designed the database like this.

Comment: Then you have little choice but to do something *similar* to what you have. You might find that creating a single large batch, using a set-based method rather than a loop, that `DELETE`s against all the table (dynamically) could be more efficient than many small batches, that `DELETE` against one table at a time.

Comment: @Larnu can you post an example as an answer? When you say "set-based" do you mean something like this with joins in the delete statement? ````DELETE messages , usersmessages  FROM messages  INNER JOIN usersmessages  
WHERE messages.messageid= usersmessages.messageid and messages.messageid = '1'````

Comment: No set-based means *not* using a loop to generate your dynamic statements, more likely you'd use string aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, although you say you can't, fixing the design would be the real solution here. If you can't do that, then reaching out whoever is responsible for being able to do so should be something you do. It appears here, for your database, you should have a single table called `Sale` and then a column called `Line` in the table with is used to denote the information represented in the table's name. As you have likely already found out, these designs don't scale (at all) and are a real pain to work with if you need to do something which affects all the tables of a particular name. The discussion of this type of design (problem) is outside the scope of the question, but there is *no* syntax like this:

```sql
DELETE 
FROM dbo.TablePrefix%
WHERE ColumnName = <Some Value>;
```

An object's name **must** be a literal, not an expression, not a wildcard.

Using a Loop is one solution, however, loops in T-SQL are pretty slow. You may, therefore, be better off creating a large batch with all your `DELETE` statements, rather than many batches with a single `DELETE` statement.

This might look something like this (I assume a *recent* version of SQL Server):

```sql
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

SELECT @SQL = STRING_AGG(N'DELETE FROM ' + QUOTENAME(s.[name]) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(t.[name]) + @CRLF +
                         N'WHERE DocNo = @DocNo;',@CRLF)
FROM sys.schemas s
     JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
WHERE t.[name] LIKE N'test$Sales Line$%';

--PRINT @SQL; --Your best friend
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@DocNo varchar(5)', @DocNo; --@DocNo's datatype is guessed.
```

If you are on an old version of SQL Server, you'll need to use a different method of string aggregation, such as the `FOR XML PATH` (and `STUFF`) method.